# Stream H264 To Android Using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, rtp, android-video-player

I'm trying to stream a .ts file containing H.264 and AAC as an RTP stream to an Android device.

I tried:

.\ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -re -i 1.ts -vcodec copy -an -f rtp rtp://127.0.0.1:10
000 -vn -acodec copy -f rtp rtp://127.0.0.1:20000 -newaudio

FFMPEG displays what should be in your SDP file and I copied this into an SDP file and tried playing from VLC and FFPLAY. VLC plays audio but just gives errors re: bad NAL unit types for video. FFPLAY doesn't play anything.

My best guess if that the FFMPEG H.264 RTP implementation is broken or at least it doesn't work in video passthru mode (i.e. using the -vcodec copy).

I need a fix for FFMPEG or an alternate simple open-source solution. I don't want to install FFMPEG in my Android client.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [vlc](http://www.videolan.org)?I once used vlc for streaming. You can have a look at [here](http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch04.html).